# Two different settings and have results side by side in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display multiple columns with multiple input options in Shiny. In the following codes, I can select one option for `ctree` depth and plot the tree as well as the data table. Now, I want to compare that with another depth input. How can I duplicate the results for another depth (such as depth = 2) and plot it next to the existing plot?
I want something like the picture I show here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTXXt.png).
Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("max", label="depth", choices=list("2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"), 
                           selected=list("3"))),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    tableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

 fit <- reactive({
   ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, 
         controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = input$max))
 })
output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    plot(fit())
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
   data 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi! All you want is to have a plot and a table side- by -side?

Comment: Hi! thank you so much. I edit my question then you can see what I need exactly with a sample image -- I want the results for two depths side-by-side @ViviG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `width` and `column` to achieve that. I used the dataset `iris` for my example as yours was not reproducible. Inside the function, `width` will control the row width, and `column` will control column width. Both widths go from 1 to 12. Divide 12 by the number of columns you wish in that row :

```
library(shiny)
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality,!is.na(Ozone))

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(width = 12, column(
  6,
  selectInput(
    "max",
    label = "depth",
    choices = list("2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"),
    selected = list("3")
  )
),
column(
  6,
  selectInput(
    "max2",
    label = "depth2",
    choices = list("2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"),
    selected = list("2")
  )
)),



mainPanel(
  width = 12,
  column(6,
         plotOutput("myPlot"),
         
         tableOutput("myTable")),
  column(6,
         plotOutput("myPlot2"),
         
         tableOutput("myTable2"))
))




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fit <- reactive({
    ctree(Ozone ~ .,
          data = airq,
          controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = input$max))
  })
  output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    plot(iris)
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    iris
  })
  output$myPlot2 = renderPlot({
    plot(iris)
  })
  
  output$myTable2 = renderTable({
    iris
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]